# Convert ext4/xfs file system to btrfs with minimal application impact

Tags: filesystems, ext4, xfs, btrfs

I'm trying to find a way to convert the file system of app servers (some of which run *ext4* and some *xfs*) to *btrfs*. Preferably, I'd like to do this without needing to turn off the services.

So far I've looked into *btrs-convert* but this requires the file system to be unmounted which will surely impact the applications.

Is this achievable in some other way?

Comment: Don't do it at all? btrfs isn't really production ready yet. Most of the data loss bugs are gone, but it's still slow and clunky.

Comment: It's required to take advantage of some of btrfs's additional functionality unfortunately

Comment: You'll have to stop the services, then, obviously.